# Rails include a json file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have a json file and I want to include json data in my devices/index.html.erb.I have kept my json file in assets/javascript/folder .Also I have generated my devices view and controller using scaffold..My json file is .So I want to know how to include this file in my rails application

```
{"records":[
 {"id":"1","gdname":"Amaresh","fdname":"Rahul","adname":"Satish","sdname":"Santosh","pdname":"Jitendra"},
  {"id":"2","gdname":"Amaresh","fdname":"Rahul","adname":"Satish","sdname":"Santosh","pdname":"Jitendra"},
 {"id":"3","gdname":"Amaresh","fdname":"Rahul","adname":"Satish","sdname":"Santosh","pdname":"Jitendra"},
   {"id":"4","gdname":"Amaresh","fdname":"Rahul","adname":"Satish","sdname":"Santosh","pdname":"Jitendra"}


]}
```

index.html.erb

```
def index
  @dealers = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join('assets/javascript', 'dealer.json')))

    @dealers = Dealer.all

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is reading the file an option?

```
# devices_controller.rb
def index
  @data = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join('assets/javascript/folder', 'myjson.json')))
  ...
end
```

You will be using it as a ruby variable which u can use in your view.

UPDATE

```
# inside devices_controller.rb

def index
  # place the file under public folder
  @dealers = JSON.parse(File.read(File.join('public','dealers.json')
  ...
end

# inside devices/index.html.erb
...
<p><%= @dealers['records']['id'] %></p>
...
```

Comment: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - assets/javascript/dealer.json

Comment: your updated code should be inside your controller action, not inside your view. And the 2nd code `@dealers = Dealer.all` is overwriting the json data

Comment: but i don't want to put my json file in public folder